# How to write this condition in C# Winform

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, winforms, c#-4.0

I have a button to choose a sender. When clicked on that button shows all sender's details such as sender ID, country, name etc. And likewise for the Receiver.

Now, if I choose one sender, it will auto populate the parent form fields with the name, country etc and likewise for the receiver.

Now, I have a business condition such that, if both the Sender and Receiver are UK, then I need to disable a combobox with a default value. Can someone please help me how to do it, as I feel that in my case, its a bit complex because, in the form, there are lot of fields and I need not necessarily fill sender first and then the recipient etc in sequence. I can fill in any sequence and ONLY if both sender and reciver details are already filled, it should immediately validate this condition and disable the combobox and if I change the sender /receiver from UK to any other country, then combo should be enabled back immediately.

I am trying to do this, however, I know there are some syntax errors. Please help me with correct syntax and also, how to check for any change in Sender/Recipient. I want to check for null condition of sender textbox and Recipient Country Combobox.

Please note - Sender is text box and Recipient is Combobox.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.txtSenderCountryCode.Text) &&
    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.cbRecipientCountry.Text))
{
    this.txtSenderCountryCode.Text == this.cbRecipientCountry.Text == "United Kingdom" ? this.cmbWeightUnit.Enabled = false : this.cmbWeightUnit.Enabled = true;
}
```

It shows me two errors:

> 1. Error  1    Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement  C:\Project\Pack\Page.cs 2739    29  Pack
> 2. Error  2    Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'string' C:\Project\Pack\Page.cs 2739    29  Pack

Comment: Why don't you simply use another if-statement instead of a ternary operator which isn't really suited for this kind of task.

Comment: @Dirk: I thought of using it, but I thought to improvise my coding skills ;-) I remember doing like this, but here the aforementioned 2 errors pops up :(

Comment: You're doing side effects in a statement where it is suppose to just return a value. Never do that!

Comment: This doesn't improves coding skills, this confuses people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ternary operator `? :` can not be used like a statement, it's an expression and returns a value. It is most commonly used like

```
variable = condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false;
SomeMethod(condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false);
```

This saves you from writing another if-statement while still keeping the code readable.

So what you want to do is (if I understood you correctly):

```
if (txtSenderCountryCode.Text == "United Kingdom" &&
    cbRecipientCountry.Text == "United Kingdom")
{
    cmbWeightUnit.Enabled = false;
}
else
{
    cmbWeightUnit.Enabled = true;
}
```

Or

```
cmbWeightUnit.Enabled = !(txtSenderCountryCode.Text == "United Kingdom" &&
                          cbRecipientCountry.Text == "United Kingdom");
```

Comment: Thank you so much Dirk, that is a comprehensive explanation for me to learn :) Helps me a lot. One more quick question, as I mentioned in my question above, how should I ensure this logic is triggered on every selection of sender/recipient. Should I write a private method and call it in Sender/Recipient button click events? Also, I will ensure to do null checking in that case for sender/recipient.

Comment: Yes, extract the logic into a private method and execute it when you think you should update the `cmbWeightUnit`. This could be whenever the user changed the `txtSenderCountryCode` TextBox or the `cbRecipientCountry` ComboBox. Without knowing details I'd use the `txtSenderCountryCode.TextChanged` and `cbRecipientCountry.SelectionChangeCommitted` events.

Comment: Thank you Dirk, that seems to be perfectly working, you opened my eyes. I am coding after long time now and just recalling all stuffs although I am kind of newbie. I just used "TextChanged" event even for combobox as because, I don't select it in our context, but when I click a button, it populates every details of recipient including country. So I think it should be ok? Thank you so much Dirk :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.txtSenderCountryCode.Text) 
    && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.cbRecipientCountry.Text))
{
    this.cmbWeightUnit.Enable = !String.Equals(this.txtSenderCountryCode.Text, "United Kingdom") 
                                && String.Equals( this.cbRecipientCountry.Text, "United Kingdom");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see (reverse engeneering) your task is to switch `cmbWeightUnit.Enabled` to 
`true` if and only if both *sender* and *recipient country* are not Greate Britain. If it's your case the code will be simple:

```
// cmbWeightUnit should be enabled unless both txtSenderCountryCode and cbRecipientCountry 
// are United Kingdom
cmbWeightUnit.Enabled = ! (String.Equals(txtSenderCountryCode.Text, "United Kingdom") &&
                           String.Equals(cbRecipientCountry.Text, "United Kingdom"));
```

If you have *many* parameters (not just *one* `cmbWeightUnit`) to set you can extract comparison into a *property*:

```
  private Boolean IsUnitedKingdom {
    get {
      return String.Equals(txtSenderCountryCode.Text, "United Kingdom") &&
             String.Equals(cbRecipientCountry.Text, "United Kingdom"); 
    }
  }

  ...

  cmbWeightUnit.Enabled = !IsUnitedKingdom;
  myCombobox.Text = IsUnitedKingdom ? "Pound" : "KGS";
  ...
```

Comment: Dmitry, thank you so much, that looks soo simple. That's exactly my condition. One more silly doubt I have. I have two values "KGS" and "Pound" and if both sender and recipient country are Great Britain, apart from disabling the combobox, I also want "KGS" to be the value in combobox. Also, again, I am confused where I would write these condition, because, as I said, I can either populate sender or Recipient first and or even other fields first. So I should be checking for null as well as I should trigger this logic if I repopulate Sender/Recipient button right?

Comment: I think, I should make a private method of this logic and call in both sender/recipient button click which populates its values. But again, only if both are not null values

Comment: @Divine: yes; a private method (or property that, IMHO, looks better here) is a nice solution.

Comment: Dmitry, that's so elegant to see, really appealing to me. Thank you so much for the advice, guidance, it helps me a lot :) :) I will use this then and make private method which I will call in the respective TextChanged events. I will test my application thoroughly as it has got multiple places dependency. If I get any issues further which I cannot endure, I will write back here surely. Thank you so much Dmitry, sorry, at this point in time, I cannot vote, at least I can give 100/100 for your answer. :)